# How can one get a non-destructive ender dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After a trip to the End where I saw the Ender Dragon, I would like it as a pet. Some advice on how to do this would really help.

Comment: I think the only way is via commands

Comment: @TimmyJim or mods

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it's impossible for Vanilla Minecraft. You would need MC Forge and the Pet Mob Mod.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it act like a friendly mob, but you can make it still and not moving:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}
```

(or `/summon ender_dragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}` for Minecraft 1.11+)

This will simply spawn a frozen Ender Dragon at the place you're standing.